# Negotiating pay for a new position in the same department shortly after getting a raise

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise

I found this question which is similar but deals with moving to a position in another company.

[Is it ok to switch a job just after getting a salary increase?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3334/is-it-ok-to-switch-a-job-just-after-getting-a-salary-increase)

I very recently received a sizable salary adjustment (about +15%) after I asked for it and made a case that I was underpaid for my contribution. A position opened in the same department but under another manager (i.e. another team) for whom I have worked for in the past. This manager asked if I was interested for this position and said that given my skills and experience the "conditions" (implying pay I am guessing) would be appropriate for a "senior person" he is looking for.

Would it appear greedy / would it be inappropriate to negotiate another higher salary given that this would be a lateral move (i.e. both positions are on the same pay scale) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, get over the idea of "Greedy."

Work is supposed to be profitable.  You are exchanging large segments of your life, arguably the most valuable thing you have, in exchange for payment.  Anyone who thinks being paid based on what you provide is "Greedy" needs to be kicked out of the conversation.

Do what you did before:  Find the appropriate pay rate for that set of skills and responsibilities in your market, and negotiate salary based on that.  "Greed" means wanting what you didn't earn or aren't entitled to.  If you earn it, and you expect to be paid appropriately, that is not greed.